# Route Polyline dissapears after zoom in osmbonuspack

Tags: android

I am able to see the route between two locations by using `OSMBonusPack`(v5.7) on Android.

But when I try to zoom in (approximately zoom level is 16 and above) then suddenly polyline is becoming invisible.

When I zoom out (zoom level is 14) again, then I can see the polyline again.

I am getting this in online mode only.
Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solution that worked for me - disable hardware acceleration. In your app manifest:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

Or, if you don't want to disable hardware acceleration in whole your application, you can always do it only for map view:

```
mapView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Solution found in this [conversation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/osmdroid/q2yUkU9KEa4/G-3CWwJEKG4J).